# Backbone - Fetch with Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a model which is doing a fetch:

```
fetch: function (options) {
  var self = this;
  var def = $.Deferred();

  P1Comm.get({
    'dataType': 'json',
    'processAjaxResponse': self.processAjaxResponse,
    'onStatusInvalid': function (e) {
      P1.log(e, 'status');
    },
    'onSuccess': function () {
      options.success;
      def.resolve();
    },
    'onError': function (e) {
      P1.log(e);
      def.reject();
    },
    'sourceURL': P1.API_APPS_ROOT + 'v1.0/accepted-terms'
  });

  return def.promise();
},
```

I have recently updated this to have the deferred functionality. However this has now broken my function in the view which sets the fetched data and puts it into the model.

```
fetchAcceptedTerms: function () {
  var self = this;
  this.appAcceptedTerms = new T1AppAcceptedTerms();
  this.acceptedTerms = new AppAcceptedTerms();

  this.acceptedTerms.fetch({
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.meta.status === 'success') {
        self.appAcceptedTerms.set(data.data);
      }
    }
  });
},
```

Before I changed the structure of the fetch to include deferred this function worked fine.

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The fetch function when it was working (before the deferred) was this:

```
fetch: function (options) {
  var self = this;

  return P1Comm.get({
    'dataType': 'json',
    'processAjaxResponse': self.processAjaxResponse,
    'onStatusInvalid': function (e) {
      P1.log(e, 'status');
    },
    'onSuccess': options.success,
    'onError': function (e) {
      P1.log(e);
    },
    'sourceURL': P1.API_APPS_ROOT + 'v1.0/accepted-terms'
  });
},
```

Comment: [`fetch` already returns a Promise](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch).

Comment: You are not calling `success` callback in `fetch` method. Add parenthesis at the end of `options.success`

Comment: You seems to be using the initial version of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37344980/2333214).  Like I mentioned in the updated answer, custom deffered is not required assuming `P1Comm.get()` returns a response. This one isn't working becuase success callback is not invoked with arguments. fix: `'onSuccess': function (data) {
     options.success(data);
      def.resolve();
    },` but I don't think this is required if `P1Comm.get()` returns promise

Comment: @AndréDion he is using a custom - overridden fetch, not the default.

Comment: @TJ, I'm suggesting there's no reason to override `fetch` here.

Comment: @AndréDion that entirely depends on unknown context. We don't know what `P1Comm` is, or how much logic it has inside it. If it's doing more than just sending an ajax call with passed in options, obviously  fetch needs to be overridden.

Comment: @AndréDion I have updated the original to include the fetch function when it was working (before the deferred). I am not much of  a front-end dev so don't have too much knowledge of any of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need the extra `Deferred` here since `get` and `fetch` already return Promise objects, but as commenters have already indicated, you're not actually calling the `options.success` function:

```
'onSuccess': function () {
  options.success;
  def.resolve();
}
```

should be

```
'onSuccess': function(data) {
  options.success(data);
  def.resolve();
}
```